# Dirac notation and spin confusion

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-spin, notation, spinors, dirac-matrices

In my book I have $$\chi = a \chi_+ + b \chi_- = \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \end{bmatrix}   \tag{1}$$

Also, $$| 1/2, 1/2\rangle = \chi_+$$

The way I see that is that $a \chi_+ =|a/2 , a/2\rangle$, but obviously from (1), $\chi_+ = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, why ?

Comment: A vector can be represented with respect to different basis vectors.

Comment: What is your background? The notation $|s,m_s\rangle$ should be familiar from angular momentum in quantum mechanics - it's not meant to be a row vector, it's just a pair of labels.

Comment: I'm still confuse...
The statement above comes from Griffith's book not me.
How come $\chi_+ = | 1/2 , 1/2 \rangle = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The thing you denote as $| 1/2, 1/2\rangle$ is a "ket" that is operated on by operators in a Hilbert space. The thing you denote by $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is a column vector (2x1 array) acted  on by matrices (2x2 arrays). The matrices are concrete representations of operators just as the column vector is a concrete representation of the ket.

Comment: It's similar to how we can abstractly write $\hat T = \frac{\hat p^2}{2m}$, but we can also write this in the position state basis as $\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$. The latter representation is easier to actually calculate with, but the former might be better for formal manipulations or generality.

Answer (score 2):

Let me note that in Griffith's book, it is not $\chi_+=|1/2,1/2\rangle$, it is $\chi_+=|\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}\rangle$, and, as @jacob1729 noted, the first fraction means that it is a state of a spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particle, and the second fraction means that it is an eigenstate of a spin component (say, $S_z$) with a positive eigenvalue. If you multiply an eigenstate by some number, you get an eigenstate with the same eigenvalue, so $a \chi_+=a|\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}\rangle$, not $|\frac{a}{2} \frac{a}{2}\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I think it is important to distinguish the *abstract state* from its *representation in a basis*.  I think Griffiths plays too fast-and-loose with the notation in this section, mixing the kets and column vector representations too liberally.  People use the Dirac notation/language in slightly different ways, but I feel like the following conventions are useful for keeping things straight.

---

In preparation, let's consider the vectors we're most familiar with coming into a QM course: vectors in three-dimensional Euclidean space.  We choose three orthogonal directions and choose special normalized vectors along these directions to be $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$, and $\hat{z}$. These will compose an orthonormal basis in which we can represent any vector $\vec{r}$ as
$$
\vec{r} = r_x\,\hat{x} + r_y\,\hat{y} + r_z\,\hat{z}\,.
$$
Once we have chosen this basis, we *represent* this abstract vector $\vec{r}$ as a column vector, i.e.,
$$
\vec{r} \to \begin{bmatrix}
r_x \\ r_y \\r_z
\end{bmatrix}\,
$$
keeping in mind that this *really* stands for the expression above; that is, we have to keep track of which basis we're using to represent the vector as  a column vector.  This is important, because, we could just as easily choose *some other* basis with which to represent the vector, and we would get a *different* column vector representation. For instance, if instead we use the basis
\begin{align}
\hat{e}_1 &= \tfrac{2}{3}\hat{x}-\tfrac{1}{3}\hat{y} + \tfrac{2}{3}\hat{z}\,, \\
\hat{e}_2 &= \tfrac{2}{3}\hat{x}+\tfrac{2}{3}\hat{y} - \tfrac{1}{3}\hat{z}\,, \\
\hat{e}_3 &= -\tfrac{1}{3}\hat{x}+\tfrac{2}{3}\hat{y} + \tfrac{2}{3}\hat{z}\,,
\end{align}
then the vector $\vec{r}$ can be written as
$$
\vec{r} = \left(\tfrac{2}{3}r_x+\tfrac{2}{3}r_y-\tfrac{1}{3}r_z\right)\hat{e}_1
+\left(-\tfrac{1}{3}r_x+\tfrac{2}{3}r_y+\tfrac{2}{3}r_z\right)\hat{e}_2
+\left(\tfrac{2}{3}r_x-\tfrac{1}{3}r_y+\tfrac{2}{3}r_z\right)\hat{e}_3\,.
$$
The column-vector representation of this vector is
$$
\vec{r} \to \begin{bmatrix}
\tfrac{2}{3}r_x+\tfrac{2}{3}r_y-\tfrac{1}{3}r_z \\
-\tfrac{1}{3}r_x+\tfrac{2}{3}r_y+\tfrac{2}{3}r_z \\
\tfrac{2}{3}r_x-\tfrac{1}{3}r_y+\tfrac{2}{3}r_z
\end{bmatrix}\,,
$$
which is *different* than the original column vector, despite representing the *same abstract vector*.

This is the reason why I notated the above with an *arrow* instead of an *equal sign*.  A representation of a vector can't be equal to the abstract vector itself. Otherwise, we'll be forced to write nonsensical things down like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\tfrac{2}{3} \\
-\tfrac{1}{3} \\
\tfrac{2}{3}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}\,,
$$
(gotten by way of $r_x = 1$, $r_y = r_z = 0$).

---

With this in hand, let's consider the abstract spin states $\lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{\pm 1}{2} \rangle$, which are eigenstates of $\hat{S}^2$ and $\hat{S}_z$ s.t.
\begin{align}
\hat{S}^2\lvert s, m_s \rangle &= \hbar^2 s(s+1)\lvert s, m_s \rangle\,, \\
\hat{S}_z\lvert s, m_s \rangle &= \hbar m_s\lvert s, m_s \rangle\,.
\end{align}
If we use these vectors as our basis (which is often done), the column vector representation of them is given by
$$
\lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{1}{2} \rangle =
(1)\lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{1}{2} \rangle + (0) \lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{- 1}{2} \rangle
\to
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\,,
$$
and
$$
\lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{-1}{2} \rangle =
(0)\lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{1}{2} \rangle + (1) \lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{1}{2} \rangle
\to
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\,.
$$
Because it is annoying to use arrows, we can give these special spinors names; let's call them
$$
\chi_+ = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\,,~~~~~~~~
\chi_- = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\,.
$$
So the names $\chi_{\pm}$ are names for the *column vector representations* of $\lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{\pm 1}{2} \rangle$ in the basis $\{\lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{\pm 1}{2} \rangle\}$. However, we could just as easily chosen another basis--e.g., the eigenstates of $\hat{S}_x$--to represent these states, and in that case we would get *some other* column vectors that we could just as well call $\chi_{\pm}$ if we wanted to, since they represent the same states.

Finally, then, we can represent an arbitrary vector in this basis as
$$
\chi = a\chi_+ + b\chi_-\,,
$$
which implicitly means
$$
\chi \to a \lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{1}{2} \rangle + b \lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{-1}{2} \rangle\,,
$$
and for consistency's sake, I might label the corresponding ket with the label $\chi$, i.e.,
$$
\chi = a\chi_+ + b\chi_- \to
\lvert \chi \rangle = 
a \lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{1}{2} \rangle + b \lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{-1}{2} \rangle\,.
$$

---

Note that this makes it much more clear what is meant by the Dirac notation and such.  Writing something like
$$
a\lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{1}{2}\rangle = 
\lvert \tfrac{a}{2}\tfrac{a}{2}\rangle\,,
$$
is non-sensical, because the stuff that goes inside the ket is the *label* for the quantum state, and multiplying a state by a number doesn't change the quantum state!  Instead, in the matrix representation,
$$
a\lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{1}{2}\rangle
\to a \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} a \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\,.
$$
We haven't changed the label of the state!  We've just made it clear that multiplying the state by $a$ is the same as multiplying all the *components* of the state (in some basis) by $a$!.

---

You will never find me writing things like
$$
\lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{1}{2} \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
or
$$
\chi_+ = \lvert \tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{1}{2} \rangle\,,
$$
because these are category errors. One can get away with this once you're comfortable with the formalism and the meaning of things. In other answers, you'll see people doing these things.  That's fine for them, because they have learned to be flexible in their thinking and are able to go back and forth between different representations in their *heads*.  But if you're not super conversant with the formalism and the notation, you will make mistakes.  Below is a common example I see in my quantum classes.

---

**Note: bad things are being witten below!**

Here is where things can get dangerous when using equal signs. I often see students equating an abstract ket $\lvert \psi \rangle$ with its position-space representation $\psi(x)$, i.e., they'll often write
$$
\lvert \psi \rangle = \psi(x)\,.
$$
**This is bad.**  What's true is that $\langle x | \psi \rangle = \psi(x)$.  The problems comes in the following.  Based on the above equality, I will often see students writing things like
$$
\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = |\psi(x)|^2\,,
$$
which is just complete nonsense, because, if normalized, this should actually be
$$
\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = 1\,,
$$
which is a number and not a function of $x$!  Indeed, in position space,
$$
\langle \psi | psi \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\,\psi^*(x) \psi(x)
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\,|\psi(x)|^2\,.
$$
This is the *least* of the problems that I see, and it leads to lots of incorrect reasoning, wrong results, and physical nonsense.  Don't do it!

Comment: Nice answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about language.
$$\chi_+ =  \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}    \equiv |1/2,1/2\rangle, \\
\chi_- =   \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}    \equiv |1/2,-1/2\rangle,
$$
Eigenvectors of the two operators below.

The two label entries in the Dirac ket correspond to ***eigenvalues*** of the operators $\sqrt{S^2/\hbar^2 + 1/4}-1/2$ and $S_z/\hbar$, respectively, where, naturally,
$$
S^2= \hbar^2 (1/2)(1/2+1) \begin{bmatrix}1  & 0\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}, \qquad S_z= \hbar \begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 0 \\ 0& -1/2 \end{bmatrix} .
$$

It is then obvious that (1) amounts to just
$$
\chi= a|1/2,1/2\rangle + b|1/2,-1/2 \rangle.
$$
Note that, in the Dirac notation, the coefficients/normalization of the ket do not naturally slide into the ket entries, as they do not   multiply the corresponding eigenvalues entered, as you may inspect directly:
$$
S^2/\hbar^2 ~a|1/2,1/2\rangle =\frac{3}{4}~~ a|1/2,1/2\rangle,\\
S_z/\hbar ~a|1/2,1/2\rangle =\frac{1}{2}~~ a|1/2,1/2\rangle  ,
$$
etc.